# How to report incorrect speed limit on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps shows the wrong speed limit for a particular road. How can I report this and correct the speed limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this specifically (possibly because you can't even see the speed limit on the web app outside of photographs — only on the mobile apps proper), so you'll just have to use the form to report a generic problem with a road:

- Open the left sidebar hamburger menu
- "Edit the map"
- "Add or fix a road"
- Click on the road
- Select the appropriate "Length of road"
- Underneath that, select "Other" and type in a description of what needs to change